# JS Slideshow with Next button

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I want my code to act like a slideshow. If I click the next button it will hide the previous image and show the other image. It will show the first image, but it doesn't' go through the loop . I also have an error that say 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang ="en">
                <head>
                <title> VIS</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>

                </head>
                <body>


                <div style="position: relative; visibility: hidden;"> 
                <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"
                          alt="Pumpkins" id="Pum"/>

                </div>

                <div style="position: relative; visibility: hidden;"> 
                <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"
                          alt="Pumpkins" id="Straw"/>

                </div>

                <div style="position: relative; visibility: hidden;"> 
                <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437"
                          alt="Pumpkins" id="Ras"/>
                </div>

                <button onclick="removeVisibility()">Next</button>

                </body>
              <script type="text/javascript" >
               function removeVisibility(){
              var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');//get all the images
              for(var i=0;i< imgs.length;i++){
                  imgs[i].style.visibility= 'visible'; //hide them
                  imgs[i-1].style.visibility= 'hidden';
              }
                          }
                </script>
                </html>
```

Comment: With every button click you loop through all the images.  So it's going to immediately display the last image every time.  Also, the first iteration of the loop is looking for `imgs[-1]` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tidipo/2/edit?html,css,output)***

You have your `DIV` (!!!) elements set to `visibility: hidden;` but you're trying desperately to change the `visibility` to `IMG`.

Now that you know your main issue, you should better go with `display none/block` if you use `position:relative` (or rather use `position: absolute` for your overlaying elements...) Any way,

- **don't use inline CSS styles! That's why we invented stylesheets!**
- don't use inline `JS`! Use `addEventListener` to attach any desired event to your elements. **Don't mix your application logic with (*view*) teplating**.

```js
var imagesHolder = document.getElementById("imagesHolder");
var images = imagesHolder.getElementsByTagName('img');
var imagesTot = images.length;
var button = document.getElementById("nextImage");
var counter = 0; // We'll use it to get the image index

function showNext(){
  counter = ++counter % imagesTot; // Increment and loop counter
  for(var i=0; i<imagesTot; i++){
    if(i != counter) images[i].style.display = "none"; // Hide all but `counter` one
  }
  // Finally show the 'counter' one!
  images[counter].style.display = "block";
}

button.addEventListener("click", showNext);
```

```css
#imagesHolder img+img{  /* SHOW ALL BUT FIRST!*/
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesHolder"> 
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1" alt="1"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2" alt="2"/>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3" alt="3"/>
</div>

<button id="nextImage">Next</button>
```

---

...but wait!

## Welcome to the world of responsive web design!

so let's add some animations and responsiveness:

```js
var imagesHolder = document.getElementById("imagesHolder"),
    images = imagesHolder.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    n = images.length,
    c = 0;

function showNext(){
  c = ++c % n;
  for(var i=0; i<n; i++) images[i].classList[i!=c?"add":"remove"]("fadeaway");
}

document.getElementById("nextImage").addEventListener("click", showNext);
showNext(); // Initial kick
```

```css
*{margin:0;}
html, body{height:100%;}
#imagesHolder{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height:90vh;
}
#imagesHolder div{
  position: absolute;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  background:50% / cover;
  transition: 1s 0s ease;
  /* Default when visible: */
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
#imagesHolder div.fadeaway{
  opacity:0;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesHolder"> 
  <div style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1);"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2);"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3);"></div>
</div>

<button id="nextImage">Next</button>
```